# Can I mount cables to the face of an unfinished garage wall?

Tags: wiring, garage

I am buying a house with a detached garage with no electric. I am going to run a line in that is ganged 15 Amp breakers.  I am planning to add 3 florescent lights and 7 or 8 outlets. I know that open walls you can not go through or over studs, but this garage is more like a pole barn than a conventional build. There is no upper sill to staple on to. How can the electric be run? I was wondering about conduit at the top of the wall.

Comment: Can you post a picture where the wall meets rafter?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I would go **20A using 12/3 wire**, same basic deal but power tools won't trip breakers near as often.  You can use common 15A outlets on 20A circuits, as long as there are 2 or more sockets in the circuit (so any twin receptacle will do).

Your next step above that is **90A using 2-2-2-4 wire**.  *Wait, why did we fly past 30A, 40A etc.? Because of how costing works. 30A with 10/3 *is the same price* as 2-2-2-4. Why pay for more and get less?  Either way you'd need a sub panel and grounding rods.   The trick is you're jumping to heavy feeder, and heavy feeder is fine with aluminum wire and always has been.  And aluminum wire is ridiculously cheaper.  (not on 15/20A because there's too little metal in those to matter).

Oh, one other factor in the decision.  People selling their homes are finding home-buyers will pay a $1000-2000 *premium* for garages that have >50A of power available in the garage.  Why? Because they think *they might* get an electric car or a plug-in hybrid.  Having the heavy feeder already out there means them not having to pay an electrician to install it.

Comment: The question didn't ask about the panel or feeder.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest much more than "ganged 15 Amp breakers". Assuming by that you mean a double-pole 15A circuit, up that to a *minimum* of 20A (which will allow for 2 20A 120V circuits), but ideally much more. The lights are "nothing", but 7 or 8 outlets means you could easily run multiple tools, space heater, etc. all at the same time. Far, far better is to run a much larger circuit (e.g., 60A) to a **subpanel**. You can then add as many circuits as you need. If you either oversize the wire (plenty of posts here about using 2 AWG aluminum) or use large-enough conduit then you can upsize later if needed.

Comment: The question didn't ask about the panel or feeder.

Comment: @isherwood I know it didn't. Sometimes people don't know what question they should really be asking. If we told OP how to install a 15A MWBC with minimalist everything, in a few months they might well be asking "How do I increase the available power so I can run more stuff at the same time" or similar. My answer - and Harper's - encourages them to plan ahead for better overall results.

Comment: _Should be asking_ and should _also_ be asking are not the same thing. You've gone way off the rails here.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* go through studs in open walls. Millions of unfinished garages and basements are done exactly like that.

Otherwise...

Cable must be reasonably protected from damage to meet code (and good sense). That means tucking it alongside framing where it extends below the ceiling, or enclosing it in conduit.

Pipe is (normally) fairly inexpensive, and that's how most pros would handle your situation. All you'd need is a hack saw and a bender. Benders are also cheap, but you could borrow or rent one.

Of course, you could box it in with lumber. Framing is framing. Doesn't much matter what the parts are. In this market that may be costly, though, and it wouldn't look too great.